# How do I avoid the loop argument

Tags: websocket, automated-tests, python-asyncio

The following code is part of some automated tests that I have written in python 3.6:

```
connected = False

def aiohttp_server(loop):
    async def handler(msg, session):
        global connected
        if msg.type == sockjs.MSG_OPEN:
            connected = True
        if msg.type == sockjs.MSG_CLOSE:
            connected = False

    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    sockjs.add_endpoint(app, handler)
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    return runner

def run_server(runner, loop):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(runner.setup())
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    loop.run_until_complete(site.start())
    loop.run_forever()

def start_server():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(aiohttp_server(loop),loop,), daemon=True)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Basically, calling start_server should initiate a simple web server with a sockjs endpoint named `/sockjs`

I am not yet a master of python's `async` keyword. There are two issues, that I suspect are related:

Firstly, I am getting a deprecation warning on the `app = web.Application(loop=loop)` statement:

```
/home/peter/incubator/sockjs_client/tests/test_sockjs_client.py:25: DeprecationWarning: loop argument is deprecated
  app = web.Application(loop=loop)
/home/peter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sockjs/route.py:54: DeprecationWarning: loop property is deprecated
  manager = SessionManager(name, app, handler, app.loop)
```

And secondly, the tests fail occasionally. I believe that, depending on machine load, sometimes the server hasn't had enough time to start before the test code actually starts executing.

Basically, what I need is for the `start_server` function to initialise a web application with a websocket endpoint, and not return until the application is prepared to accept websocket connections.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure what to answer. But regarding depreciation, the parameter `loop` is.. deprecated.
Read more here [doc][1]


  [1]: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Application.loop "doc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, I am getting a deprecation warning on the app = `web.Application(loop=loop)` statement:

The recommended way to avoid passing around the `loop` everywhere is to switch to [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run). Instead of managing the loop manually, let `asyncio.run` create (and close) the loop for you. If all your work is done in coroutines, you can access the loop with `get_event_loop()` or `get_running_loop()`.

> Basically, what I need is for the start_server function to initialise a web application with a websocket endpoint, and not return until the application is prepared to accept websocket connections.

You can pass a `threading.Event` to the thread that gets set when the site is set up, and wait for it in the main thread.

Here is an (untested) example that implements both suggestions:

```py
connected = False

def aiohttp_server():
    async def handler(msg, session):
        global connected
        if msg.type == sockjs.MSG_OPEN:
            connected = True
        if msg.type == sockjs.MSG_CLOSE:
            connected = False

    app = web.Application()
    sockjs.add_endpoint(app, handler)
    return web.AppRunner(app)

async def run_server(ready):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    runner = aiohttp_server()
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    await site.start()
    ready.set()
    # emulates loop.run_forever()
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()

def start_server():
    ready = threading.Event()
    threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(aiohttp_server(ready),),
                     daemon=True).start()
    ready.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solves my 'DeprecationWarning'. However, the test fails about fifty percent of the time with a 'RuntimeError: Event loop is closed'

Comment: @spierepf It's hard to tell what the issue is there without a minimal working example or a stack trace. Perhaps that should be asked as a separate question

Comment: fair enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525819/preventing-random-runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-in-automated-test

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade sockjs to the newest version.
It doesn't require passing the *loop* anymore.